# Add multiple QFrames into a single QFrame at runtime while using MSVC

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt4

I am creating a main window having a number of frames as child frames on it. I want to add these frames at runtime and i am using the following code.
in NFrame.h

***In NFrame.h*** 
`QList<QFrame *> nFrame;`

and initialize them in NFrame.cpp as

***In Nframe.cpp***

```
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
        nFrame[i] = new QFrame(this); 
        nFrame[i]->show();
}
```

Is this a correct way to do this or i have to do something else.

Comment: looks good to me, whats the problem?

Comment: Thanks @Zaiborg for your reply & the main problem was that whenever i was adding all these frames to my _mainwindow_ using _gridlayout_ then it was crashing my Mainwindow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my mistake in the above code. I was trying to initialize a QList with a new Instance of of **QFrame**. As structure of **QList** is very much similar to an array so In the QList we can add items either by**insert()** method or by **append()**. 
The following code correct my mistakes.

`for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
         nFrame.append(new QFrame(this));
         nFrame[i]->show();
    }`